# Why I do not get the proper Counts based on id and another column, in R?

Tags: r, count, tidyverse

I am trying to get the right counts of comorbidities based on two columns, id and comorbidity (which has different types of comorbidites) with tidyverse library in R. I am trying to understand why I do not get it right? since I apply the obvious, see bellow:

This is the structure of the data:

```
structure(list(id = c("133", "cd5", "392", "ffa", "6ed", "9a2", 
"989", "870", "2d9", "f9e", "d36", "8f4", "fb8", "626", "8fb", 
"aea", "aea", "af4", "162", "162"), Comorbidity_count = c("Comorbidity_one", 
"Comorbidity_one", "Comorbidity_one", "Comorbidity_one", "Comorbidity_one", 
"Comorbidity_one", "Comorbidity_one", "Comorbidity_one", "Comorbidity_one", 
"Comorbidity_one", "Comorbidity_one", "Comorbidity_one", "Comorbidity_one", 
"Comorbidity_one", "Comorbidity_one", "Comorbidity_one", "Comorbidity_two", 
"Comorbidity_one", "Comorbidity_one", "Comorbidity_two"), Comorbidity = c("None", 
"None", "None", "High Blood Pressure (hypertension)", "None", 
"None", "None", "Asthma (managed with an inhaler)", "None", "None", 
"None", "None", "None", "None", "None", "Diabetes Type 2", "Obesity", 
"None", "High Blood Pressure (hypertension)", "Obesity")), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), groups = structure(list(id = c("133", "cd5", "392", "ffa", 
"6ed", "9a2", "989", "870", "2d9", "f9e", "d36", "8f4", "fb8", 
"626", "8fb", "aea", "aea", "af4", "162", "162"), .rows = structure(list(
    7L, 6L, 16:17, 19:20, 11L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 8L, 2L, 14L, 9L, 15L, 
    10L, 12L, 13L, 18L, 1L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
"vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, 18L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

if I write the code bellow I do not get the right counts:

```
    count_id <- test %>%
      naniar::replace_with_na(replace = list(Comorbidity = "None")) %>%
      dplyr::group_by(id, Comorbidity) %>%
      dplyr::mutate(number_morbidities = n())
```

And the outcome should be looking as per table bellow:

```
structure(list(id = c("133", "cd5", "392", "ffa", "6ed", "9a2", 
"989", "870", "2d9", "f9e", "d36", "8f4", "fb8", "626", "8fb", 
"aea", "aea", "af4", "162", "162"), Comorbidity_count = c("Comorbidity_one", 
"Comorbidity_one", "Comorbidity_one", "Comorbidity_one", "Comorbidity_one", 
"Comorbidity_one", "Comorbidity_one", "Comorbidity_one", "Comorbidity_one", 
"Comorbidity_one", "Comorbidity_one", "Comorbidity_one", "Comorbidity_one", 
"Comorbidity_one", "Comorbidity_one", "Comorbidity_one", "Comorbidity_two", 
"Comorbidity_one", "Comorbidity_one", "Comorbidity_two"), Comorbidity = c(NA, 
NA, NA, "High Blood Pressure (hypertension)", NA, NA, NA, "Asthma (managed with an inhaler)", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "Diabetes Type 2", "Obesity", NA, 
"High Blood Pressure (hypertension)", "Obesity"), number_morbidities = c(NA, 
NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2L, 2L, 
NA, 2L, 2L)), row.names = c(NA, -20L), groups = structure(list(
    id = c("133", "162", "2d9", "392", "626", "6ed", "870", "8f4", 
    "8fb", "989", "9a2", "aea", "af4", "cd5", "d36", "f9e", "fb8", 
    "ffa"), .rows = structure(list(1L, 19:20, 9L, 3L, 14L, 5L, 
        8L, 12L, 15L, 7L, 6L, 16:17, 18L, 2L, 11L, 10L, 13L, 
        4L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", "vctrs_vctr", 
    "list"))), row.names = c(NA, 18L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to group by `id` only, since you want the count per id, and use a different approach to count comorbidities if you want to ignore ids with no comorbidities. `n()` will count all rows whether missing or not. Note that this approach produces 0 if there are no comorbidities, which I think is more meaningful than `NA`; you can replace the 0 with `NA` if you need to. Note that I also skipped the `naniar` dependency but that doesn't change anything.

```r
library(tidyverse)
test <- structure(list(id = c("133", "cd5", "392", "ffa", "6ed", "9a2", "989", "870", "2d9", "f9e", "d36", "8f4", "fb8", "626", "8fb", "aea", "aea", "af4", "162", "162"), Comorbidity_count = c("Comorbidity_one", "Comorbidity_one", "Comorbidity_one", "Comorbidity_one", "Comorbidity_one", "Comorbidity_one", "Comorbidity_one", "Comorbidity_one", "Comorbidity_one", "Comorbidity_one", "Comorbidity_one", "Comorbidity_one", "Comorbidity_one", "Comorbidity_one", "Comorbidity_one", "Comorbidity_one", "Comorbidity_two", "Comorbidity_one", "Comorbidity_one", "Comorbidity_two"), Comorbidity = c("None", "None", "None", "High Blood Pressure (hypertension)", "None", "None", "None", "Asthma (managed with an inhaler)", "None", "None", "None", "None", "None", "None", "None", "Diabetes Type 2", "Obesity", "None", "High Blood Pressure (hypertension)", "Obesity")), row.names = c(NA, -20L), groups = structure(list(id = c("133", "cd5", "392", "ffa", "6ed", "9a2", "989", "870", "2d9", "f9e", "d36", "8f4", "fb8", "626", "8fb", "aea", "aea", "af4", "162", "162"), .rows = structure(list(7L, 6L, 16:17, 19:20, 11L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 8L, 2L, 14L, 9L, 15L, 10L, 12L, 13L, 18L, 1L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, 18L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

test %>%
  mutate(Comorbidity = if_else(Comorbidity == "None", NA_character_, Comorbidity)) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(number_morbidities = sum(!is.na(Comorbidity)))
#> # A tibble: 20 x 4
#> # Groups:   id [18]
#>    id    Comorbidity_count Comorbidity                        number_morbidities
#>    <chr> <chr>             <chr>                                           <int>
#>  1 133   Comorbidity_one   <NA>                                                0
#>  2 cd5   Comorbidity_one   <NA>                                                0
#>  3 392   Comorbidity_one   <NA>                                                0
#>  4 ffa   Comorbidity_one   High Blood Pressure (hypertension)                  1
#>  5 6ed   Comorbidity_one   <NA>                                                0
#>  6 9a2   Comorbidity_one   <NA>                                                0
#>  7 989   Comorbidity_one   <NA>                                                0
#>  8 870   Comorbidity_one   Asthma (managed with an inhaler)                    1
#>  9 2d9   Comorbidity_one   <NA>                                                0
#> 10 f9e   Comorbidity_one   <NA>                                                0
#> 11 d36   Comorbidity_one   <NA>                                                0
#> 12 8f4   Comorbidity_one   <NA>                                                0
#> 13 fb8   Comorbidity_one   <NA>                                                0
#> 14 626   Comorbidity_one   <NA>                                                0
#> 15 8fb   Comorbidity_one   <NA>                                                0
#> 16 aea   Comorbidity_one   Diabetes Type 2                                     2
#> 17 aea   Comorbidity_two   Obesity                                             2
#> 18 af4   Comorbidity_one   <NA>                                                0
#> 19 162   Comorbidity_one   High Blood Pressure (hypertension)                  2
#> 20 162   Comorbidity_two   Obesity                                             2
```

<sup>Created on 2020-08-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: apparently, when I apply the code on a bigger dataset it does not work. This is an issue I've got for a while already... When I apply on a bigger dataset then I get twice as much. For example 1 comorbity turns into 2, 2 turns into 4. A bit weird and do not know why

Comment: Calum You I've posted another question with regards to this aspect. Apparently, my wrong counts is due to big dataset I am trying to run my Count.